# Adding an appsetting to the root web.config file in a helix solution

Tags: sitecore, helix

We are trying to figure out how to add an appsetting into the root websites web.config from a helix feature project.  Its my understanding that if you add a transform file e.g (web.config.transform) into the root of your feature project and build the project using the helix gulp script, the transform should update the root  config.  Is this correct?  Unfortunately when we run the gulp script we get an error

```
    [11:26:54] Starting '04-Apply-Xml-Transform'...
[11:26:55] Applying configuration transform: D:\Projects\xxxxxxx\src\Feature\Claims\code\xxxxx.Website.Feature.Claim\App_Config\Include\Web.config.transform
D:\Projects\xxxxxxx\scripts\applytransform.targets(14,5): error : Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxx\website\xxxxxxx.Website.Feature.Claim\App_Config\Include\Web.config'.
Process terminated with code 1.
[11:26:56] MSBuild failed with code 1!
[11:26:56] '04-Apply-Xml-Transform' errored after 1.59 s
error!
[11:26:56] Error: MSBuild failed with code 1!
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\xxxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\gulp-msbuild\lib\msbuild-runner.js:66:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
```

It looks to me as like it is trying to update a local web.config.

Comment: Do you have a broken config transform file reference in your project? File linked from project but missing on your drive?

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config would not reside here `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxx\website\xxxxxxx.Website.Feature.Claim\App_Config\Include\Web.config`

It would reside here: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxxxxx\website\Web.config`